# Construct a graph with given properties

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

> For any $k \ge 3$ construct a non hamiltonian, connected, $k$-homogeneous and two sided graph.

I tried to use induction, but couldn't construct for $k=3$ or $4$.

Any hints or advices appreciated